# Importing data to localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, local-storage

Could anybody help me out sorting the following code or help me in the right direction?

It needs to import data from a .txt file and store it into localstorage as key & value.

Key is before ':' and value comes after it. A new key / value is separated after each ','.

Sample data from .txt file is:

> nl-step1chapter1Question6:U2FsdGVkX19bRT84xShxK+29ypgj1d6ZHt+2DVBCUtY=,nl-step1chapter1Question1:U2FsdGVkX1+/Sv61L69bLvQGTkf1A9Uy4jgJ3KZTkzI=,nl-step1chapter1Question4:U2FsdGVkX1+9SVVOvTKeZuaQGj58L5WnEgL8htS0c7U=,jft:320982da-f32a-46a2-a97c-605ebe305518,nl-step1chapter1Question5:U2FsdGVkX19pi8A+PQZ7rBNCWrFeCwl2HdXpV+wWkFk=,nl-step1chapter1Question2:U2FsdGVkX19hnRnpmP3omzYNU0jXd3NtsHM+mvGYBnc=,nl-step1chapter1Question3:U2FsdGVkX1+hPbMRN+x19y7pF73eXoxG0qK1igZYZbA=

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/x-javascript">
$(function importData() {
    document.getElementById('file').onchange = function () {
        //debugger;
        var file = this.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (progressEvent) {
            //console.log(this.result.split(','));

            var lines = this.result.split(',');

            var list = [];

            for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
                list.push(lines[line]);
                localStorage.setItem([line],lines);
            }
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    };
});
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using `FileReader` doesn't seem correct to me. This is how your `importData()` function should be:

```
$(function importData() {
    document.getElementById('file').onchange = function (event) {
        var input = event.target;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            var text = reader.result;
            var lines = text.split(',');

            for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
              let elements = lines[line].split(':');
              localStorage.setItem(elements[0], elements[1]);
            }
        };

        reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
    };
});
```

It will insert the elements in the `localStorage` as you described. For example: `key` = `step1chapter1Question1` and `value` = `U2FsdGVkX1+/Sv61L69bLvQGTkf1A9Uy4jgJ3KZTkzI=`